# Openssl failed EVP CIPHER

Tags: c, openssl

I want to use OpenSSL1.1.1k to construct an sm4 cmodel program.

But it seems not support sm4 feature as it compile the warnings below and meet the segmentation fault at the EVP_EncryptInit_ex function with EVP_CIPHER EVP_sm4_cbc().

```
../code/sm4.c:83:17: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                 return EVP_sm4_ecb();
                 ^
../code/sm4.c:85:17: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                 return EVP_sm4_cbc();
                 ^
../code/sm4.c:87:17: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                 return EVP_sm4_cfb128();
```

But when I changed it to EVP_aes_128_cbc(), the program runs successfully.

I use the code on this site:https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_42282031/article/details/108627678/

Code detailed as below:

```
//sm4.h
#ifndef _SM4_H_
#define _SM4_H_

#include <stdint.h>

#define SM4_BLOCK_SIZE       (16)

typedef struct
{
    void *ctx;
    void *key;
    void *iv;
    void *mode;
}sm4_data_t;

#define SM4_MODE_ECB    "0_ecb"
#define SM4_MODE_CBC    "1_cbc"
#define SM4_MODE_CFB    "2_cfb"

int32_t sm4_gen_key(sm4_data_t *data, uint8_t *key, uint32_t length);
int32_t sm4_gen_iv(sm4_data_t *data, uint8_t *iv, uint32_t length);

int32_t sm4_encrypt_data(sm4_data_t *data, void *in, uint32_t ilen, void *out, uint32_t *olen);
int32_t sm4_decrypt_data(sm4_data_t *data, void *in, uint32_t ilen, void *out, uint32_t *olen);

int32_t sm4_data_init(sm4_data_t *data, void *mode);
int32_t sm4_data_exit(sm4_data_t *data);

#endif
```

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sm4.h"

static uint8_t txt[] = {
    0xf5, 0xa0, 0x3b, 0x06, 0x48, 0xd2, 0xc4 ,0x63, 0x0e, 0xea, 0xc5, 0x13, 0xe1, 0xbb, 0x81, 0xa1,
    0x59, 0x44, 0xda, 0x38, 0x27, 0xd5, 0xb7, 0x41, 0x43, 0xac, 0x7e, 0xac, 0xee, 0xe7, 0x20, 0xb3,
    0xb1, 0xb6, 0xaa, 0x29, 0xdf, 0x21, 0x2f, 0xd8, 0x76, 0x31, 0x82, 0xbc, 0x0d, 0x42, 0x1c, 0xa1,
    0xbb, 0x90, 0x38, 0xfd, 0x1f, 0x7f, 0x42, 0xd4, 0x84, 0x0b, 0x69, 0xc4, 0x85, 0xbb, 0xc1, 0xaa,
    0x11, 0x22,
};

static int32_t show_hex(int8_t* title, void* buf, uint32_t total)
{
    uint32_t idx;
    uint8_t* data = buf;

    printf("%s(%d):\n\t", title, total);
    for (idx = 0; idx < total; idx++) {
        printf("%02hhx", data[idx]);
        printf("%s", 15 == (idx & 15) ? "\n\t" : ", ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}

int32_t main(void)
{
    uint8_t key[16] = {0};
    uint8_t iv[16] = {0};
    uint8_t cipher[128] = {0};
    uint8_t buf[128] = {0};
    uint32_t len;
    sm4_data_t data;

    if (sm4_data_init(&data, SM4_MODE_CBC)) {
        return -1;
    }

    sm4_gen_key(&data, key, sizeof(key));
    sm4_gen_iv(&data, iv, sizeof(iv));
    show_hex("key", key, sizeof(key));
    show_hex("iv", iv, sizeof(iv));

    show_hex("data", txt, sizeof(txt));
    sm4_encrypt_data(&data, txt, sizeof(txt), cipher, &len);

    show_hex("cipher", cipher, len);

    sm4_decrypt_data(&data, cipher, len, buf, &len);
    show_hex("buf", buf, len);

    sm4_data_exit(&data);
    return 0;
}

static void sm4_show_openssl_error(int8_t* title)
{
    int8_t buf[1024];

    ERR_error_string_n(ERR_get_error(), buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("%s: %s\n", title, buf);
}


static const EVP_CIPHER *sm4_get_mode(int8_t *mode)
{
switch (*mode) {
        case '0':
                return EVP_sm4_ecb();
        case '1':
                return EVP_sm4_cbc();
        case '2':
                return EVP_sm4_cfb128();
        default:
                return NULL;
        }   
}

static int32_t sm4_get_rand(uint8_t *out, uint32_t len)
{   
    BIGNUM *rnd;
    uint8_t buf[32];
    uint32_t idx;
    
    rnd = BN_new();
    if (NULL == rnd) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (!BN_rand(rnd, 256, 1, 1)) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (BN_bn2binpad(rnd, buf, 32) != 32) {
        return -1;
    }
    BN_free(rnd);
    show_hex("rand", buf, 32);
    
    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
        idx = idx >= 32 ? 0 : idx;
        *out++ = buf[idx];
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_gen_key(sm4_data_t *data, uint8_t *key, uint32_t length)
{
    if (sm4_get_rand(key, length)) {
        return -1;
    }
    data->key = key;

    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_gen_iv(sm4_data_t *data, uint8_t *iv, uint32_t length)
{
    if (sm4_get_rand(iv, length)) {
        return -1;
    }
    data->iv = iv;

    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_encrypt_data(sm4_data_t *data, void *in, uint32_t ilen, void *out, uint32_t *olen)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = data->ctx;
    const EVP_CIPHER *mode = sm4_get_mode(data->mode);
    int32_t len = 0, pad = 0;

    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, mode, NULL, data->key, data->iv);

    if (ilen % SM4_BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
        pad = 1;
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, pad);

    if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, ilen)) {
        return -1;
    }
    *olen = len;
    len = 0;

    if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, out + *olen, &len)) {
        return -1;
    }

    *olen += len;

    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_decrypt_data(sm4_data_t *data, void *in, uint32_t ilen, void *out, uint32_t *olen)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = data->ctx;
    const EVP_CIPHER *mode = sm4_get_mode(data->mode);
    int32_t len = 0;

    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, mode, NULL, data->key, data->iv);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);

    if (!EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, out, &len, in, ilen)) {
        return -1;
    }
    *olen = len;
    len = 0;

    if (EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, out + *olen, &len)) {
        return -1;
    }
    *olen += len;

    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_data_init(sm4_data_t *data, void *mode)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (NULL == ctx) {
        return -1;
    }   

    data->mode = mode;
    data->ctx = ctx;

    return 0;
}

int32_t sm4_data_exit(sm4_data_t *data)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(data->ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Best Regards.

Comment: You probably also have a few *Implicit Declaration*... warnings as well. Looks like the compiler can't find the declarations for the `EVP_sm4_ecb()` ... functions so in C the default type `int` is presumed -- thus the mismatch `"makes pointer from integer..."`. Double check you have all necessary headers included. `openssl/evp.h` should cover it per [EVP_sm4_cbc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_sm4_ecb.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems that I only use -l to indicate the library path, and it uses the default include path of the old version OpenSSL so when I use 'openssl version' command in Linux it shows 1.1.1k version. But when I try it in c code, it didn't support the sm4_ecb with the old version header file.  So I add the -I to indicate the correct include path to solve the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. Always dicey to have multiple versions installed -- but so long as you are careful about the include paths -- you can have as many as you like.